# Exception:Insufficient memory to continue the execution of this operation in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I created a camera capture inside my windows phone 8.1 app.while opening the camera second time i got an exception that "insufficient memory to complete this operation". I don't know what the problem is. I'm entirely new to windows phone 8.1 app developement. Can anybody help me out with this problem.thanks in advance.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2494124 (Are you running the latest OS updates?)

Comment: thnks boss..microsoft support providing only hotfix for vs 2013.im using vs 2015..is 2013 version suits for my version?